# Adding comments section to website integrated WordPress instance

Tags: comments, plugin-jetpack, customization

We've integrated a WP instance into our website, and I was wondering how to render the comments template into the page.

I've tried simply adding:

```
    comments_template( '', true );
```

But it doesn't seem to work (also there are no errors shown).

I guess we are missing some includes and inits. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a `comments.php` file in your theme?

Answer (score 1):

Could be as simple as using the full function in the template file:

`<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>`

Be sure you have a comments.php file in the theme folder.

And be sure you're using the full loop:

```
<?php
require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

**See [Integrating WordPress with Your Website « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)**